# how could we store other values in list partition in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

how could we store other values in list partition in postgresql?

Sample: How can i add a partition for different values than (1,2,3,4) in table below.

```
CREATE TABLE countrymeasurements
(
  countrycode int NOT NULL,
  countryname character varying(30) NOT NULL,
  languagename character varying (30) NOT NULL,
  daysofoperation character varying(30) NOT NULL,
  salesparts    bigint,
  replaceparts  bigint
)
PARTITION BY LIST(countrycode);
Define the partitions:

create table india 
  partition of countrymeasurements 
  for values in (1);
  
create table japan
  partition of countrymeasurements 
  for values in (2);
  
create table china
  partition of countrymeasurements 
  for values in (3);

create table malaysia
  partition of countrymeasurements 
  for values in (4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Found out the solution now:

```
create table dwh_user.countrymeasurements_def 
partition of countrymeasurements 
default;
```

Comment: Beware. While this will work as you expect, it may prevent you from adding new partitions later: you cannot add a partition if there is already a value in the default partition that would belong in the new partition.